# Verifying simplification of simple logic expressions

Tags: logic, solution-verification

I am trying to simplifying these 3 expressions, and I have actually done them, but can someone check if it's correct? Thank you.

- $x \vee y \land y \vee \neg x$
- $x \land y \vee y \land \neg x$
- $\neg(\neg(x \land y) \vee x)\vee y$

The first one:

$x \vee y \land y \vee \neg x = x\vee(y)\vee\neg x = (x\vee\neg x)\vee y=1\vee y=1$

Second one:

$x\land y \vee y \land \neg x = (x \land y) \vee (y \land \neg x) = (y \land x) \vee (y \land \neg x) = y \land (x \vee \neg x) = y \land 1 = y$

Third one:

$\neg(\neg(x\land y)\vee x)\vee y = \neg(\neg x \vee \neg y \vee x) \vee y = \neg(1\vee\neg y)\vee y=\neg(1)\vee y=0\vee y=y$

Thank you for helping.

Comment: In the first two formulas, where are the parentheses? Without them there is ambiguity, if no rule gives priority to a connective to another.

Comment: It seems correct if we compute $\land$ in prior to $\lor$.

Comment: Oh in the text I am reading, it says $\land$ is prioritized over $\vee$ and $\neg$ over $\land$.

Comment: The computation is correct if $\land$ ">" $\vee$? Okay, thank you. @HanulJeon Also I wonder if question like this is acceptable? Like there's not much to answer other than :"yes it's correct" (or "no it's wrong, heres why: ...")

Comment: @GarethMa You explained all of your attempts. So it is fine, at least for me.

Comment: Thank you for helping :)

Comment: @GarethMa The tag 'solution-verification' is for exactly this.

Comment: Thank you for that. Learning everyday haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are all correct.   Also, your steps are clear, so it was easy to follow your reasoning.